# How can I pay someone in another country?

Tags: transactions

I have my wallet with some BTC in it, on my PC, and I live in europe. Let's say I want to pay 2BTC to a company in India or China, or whatever, but they don't accept BTC. They only take Indian Rupees (INR) or Chinese Yuan (CNY).

Now my question: is there any way to send BTC to their country, then those BTC become Rupees, and these workers can just walk to their bank to get their money? Or some other easy way to pay them without fees or at least the smallest fees possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

They could open an account at [btcxindia.com](https://btcxindia.com/wallet/) or another exchange in India. You send the BTC to their account there and then they just sell and widthdraw the rupees to their bank account.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your BTC converted to INR (CNY) using some standard websites (Example [bitcxindia](https://btcxindia.com/) or unocoin). This will require an indian ( chinese) bank account. And then pay the concerned people in INR (CNY) via that bank.

Comment: "This will require an indian ( chinese) bank account." This defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

First, buy bitcoins, then go to local bitcoins in their country. Get their account details, and start a transaction depositing into their bank account.